# $||B\mathbf{x}||_2 \leq \overline{\sigma}(B)||\mathbf{x}||_2$ proof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\overline{\sigma}(B)$ is the maximum singular value of a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (equivalent to $||B||$ by some definitions ) and $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then

$||B\mathbf{x}||_2 \leq \overline{\sigma}(B)||\mathbf{x}||_2$

My question is whether the following proof of the above is rigorous, and if there is a simpler way:

1. $\overline{\sigma}(B)||\mathbf{x}||_2 = \smash{\displaystyle\max_{\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}}}\left(\frac{||B\mathbf{x}||_2}{||\mathbf{x}||_2}\right)||\mathbf{x}||_2$
2. Say $\mathbf{\hat{x}}=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{||\mathbf{x}||_2}$. Then $\frac{||B\mathbf{x}||_2}{||\mathbf{x}||_2}=\frac{||B\mathbf{\hat{x}}||\mathbf{x}||_2||_2}{||\mathbf{x}||_2}=||B\mathbf{\hat{x}}||_2$
3. Therefore $\frac{||B\mathbf{x}||_2}{||\mathbf{x}||_2}$ is independent of $||\mathbf{x}||_2$ so we can take $||\mathbf{x}||_2$ out of $\smash{\displaystyle\max_{\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}}}\left(\frac{||B\mathbf{x}||_2}{||\mathbf{x}||_2}\right)$.
4. $\overline{\sigma}(B)||\mathbf{x}||_2=\smash{\displaystyle\max_{\mathbf{x}\neq \mathbf{0}}}\left(||B\mathbf{x}||_2\right)\geq ||B\mathbf{x}||_2$

I'm least convinced about step 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\frac{||B\mathbf{x}||_2}{||\mathbf{x}||_2}$ is independent of $||\mathbf{x}||_2$

sounds rather nonsensical to me.

A simpler and rigourous way:

$$\overline{\sigma}(B) = \smash{\displaystyle\max_{\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}}}\left(\frac{||B\mathbf{x}||_2}{||\mathbf{x}||_2}\right) \implies \frac{||B\mathbf{x}||_2}{||\mathbf{x}||_2} \le \overline{\sigma}(B) \hspace{1 cm}(\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}) $$

Hence $||B\mathbf{x}||_2 \leq \overline{\sigma}(B)||\mathbf{x}||_2$ if $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}$. Furthermore, if $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ the inequality is also true - hence is true in general.

Comment: I would argue that while step 3 may not be elegant, it is correct. But your proof is much simpler and nicer, thanks very much